# Extracting contents of many zipped folders into a single directory

Tags: bash, unix, directory, zip, extract

Kind of easy question, but I can't find the answer. I want to extract the contents of multiple zipped folders into a single directory. I am using the bash console, which is the only tool available on the particular website I am using.

For example, I have two folders: a.zip (which contains a1.txt and a2.txt) and b.zip (which contains b1.txt and b2.txt). I want to get extract all four text files into a single directory.

I have tried

```
unzip \*.zip -d \newdirectory
```

But it creates two directories (a and b) with two text files in each.

I also tried concatenating the two zipped folders into one big folder and extracting it, but it still creates two directories, even when I specify a new directory.

I can't figure what I am doing wrong. Any help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @sjsam, but I still get the two directories (with two text files in each).

Comment: Use the `-j` parameter for not creating paths..that is `unzip -j -d /path/to/your/directory '*.zip*'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-j` parameter to ignore any directory structure.

```
unzip -j -d /path/to/your/directory '*.zip*'
```

Comment: You're welcome !! By the way, unzip should not create a directory on its own.  Anyway the `-j` will make the unzip forget the directory structure altogether.